# Exercise 1.16. For each positive real t, let $X_{t} = ( -t, t)$ and $Y_{t} =[ -t,t]$. ? Please check my answer and comment on it

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Exercise 1.16. For each positive real t, let $X_{t} = ( -t, t)$ and $Y_{t} =[ -t,t]$.

Describe

(i)$\bigcup_{t > 0}  X_{t}$  and $\bigcup_{t > 0} Y_{t}$
$(-t,t)$

(ii) $\bigcup_{0< t < 10} X_{t}$  and $\bigcup_{0< t < 10}  Y_{t}$

$(-10,10)$

(iii)$ \bigcup_{0< t ≤ 10} X_{t}$  and  $\bigcup_{0< t ≤ 10} Y_{t}  $

$(-10,10)$

are these correct?

(iv)$ \bigcap_{t ≥ 10} X_{t}$  and $\bigcap_{t ≥ 10}  Y_{t}$

And this is the union, I suppose the answer is [-10,10]?

(iv)$⋂_{t > 10} X_{t}$  and $⋂_{t > 10} Y_{t}$

And the answer is $(-10,10)$?

(iv)$⋂_{t > 0} X_{t}$  and $⋂_{t > 0} Y_{t}$

And the answer is $(-\infty,0) ∪ (0, \infty)$ ?

If I am not right, would you mind comment on each one of them briefly?

Comment: (i) is $(-\infty, \infty)$ for both $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$.

Comment: Your "answers" don't match up very well with the Questions.  It's a bit hard to believe you didn't realize each part requires consideration of two sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) You take the union over all $t>0$ not just until some specific $t$.

Solution:

> The solution is in both cases $\mathbb{R}$, since for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $x\in X_{|x|+1}$ and $x\in Y_{|x|}$.

(ii) Right.

(iii) $\bigcup_{0<t\leq 10} X_t=(-10,10)$ is right, but not $\bigcup_{0<t\leq 10} Y_t$.

Solution:

> $\bigcup_{0<t\leq 10} Y_t=[-10,10]$, since $Y_{10}=[-10,10]$ is the largest set in the union.

(iv) $\bigcap_{t\geq 10} Y_t=[-10,10]$ is right, but not the other set.

Solution:

> $\bigcap_{t\geq 10} X_t=(-10,10)$. Consider $10\notin X_{10}$.

(v) Both cases wrong.

Solution:

> Since $10\in X_t$ and $10\in Y_t$ for all $t>10$ you get $\bigcap_{t>10}X_t=[-10,10]=\bigcap_{t>10} Y_t$.

(vi) Both cases wrong.

Solution:

> Consider $x\neq 0$, then $x\notin X_t$ and $x\notin Y_t$ if $t<|x|$. Therefore $\bigcap_{t>0}X_t=\{0\}=\bigcap_{t>0}Y_t$.

Warning: The solutions contain no complete proof, just the right set and a remark.

**Edit:**

Proof of (v).

a) Claim 1: $A:=\bigcap_{t>10} X_t=[-10,10]=:B$.

Proof of $A\subseteq B$:

Let be $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus B$. Then $|x|>10$. There exists $10<s<|x|$ and you get $x\notin X_s\supset \bigcap_{t>10} X_t=A$ and we get $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus X_s\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus A$.

Proof of $A\supseteq B$:

Let be $x\in B$. By definition of intersection there holds
$$
x\in\bigcap_{t>10} X_t \Leftrightarrow \left(x\in X_t~\forall t>10\right).
$$
Since the RHS is true, you get $x\in A$.

Together we proved $A=B$, which was the claim 1.

b) Claim 2: $A:=\bigcap_{t>10} Y_t=[-10,10]=:B$.

Proof of Claim 2 is **exactly** the same as for claim 1. Just change $X_t$ to $Y_t$.

Comment: @ Mundron Schmidt thanks, for notation-wise,on (i), you put $X_{x+1}$ instead of $X_{t+1}$, why?

Comment: Because $x\notin (-|x|,|x|)=X_{|x|}$ but $x\in(-(|x|+1),|x|+1)=X_{|x|+1}$.

Comment: @ Mundron Schmidt On (v), shouldn't the answer be (-10,10) for both cases?

Comment: @Tmm I fixed $\bigcup$ to $\bigcap$ in (iv), (v) and (vi). But my answer is right. Consider the point $10$. It is contained in $X_t$ and $Y_t$ for all $t>10$ and therefore it is in the intersection of all these sets. You have to be careful. Since you intersect less sets, you get maybe a bigger intersection. And exactly that happens in (v) compared to (iv)

Comment: about (v), my professor argues that it is (-10,10) instead of [-10,10]. He said that if I take limit on the boundary t does not contain 10. Do you have a solid argument that I can disprove my professor's answer? Caused I tend to agree with your answer

Comment: I added the proof of (v) at the end. Show it your professor and if he finds a gap in my proof, then please tell me.